# removing cached information from ajax call in the modal dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, caching

I am displaying a modal(bootstrap) dialog when a user clicks on a row of a table. Here is a small piece of code that I am using :

```
.done (function (data_, textStatus_, jqXHR_) {
        $('<pre/>').html(doc_contents[1].text_content).appendTo('#employee_document_contents');
        $('#mydialog').modal("show"); 
        $('#mydialog').draggable(); 

});
```

The above code is grabbing a JSON value and displaying in the dialog. I am facing cache related problem I believe in my ajax call. The previous contents of the dialog are not getting removed and I have to basically clear the cache from my browser and click on a particular row again to see what I want to see.I tried using `cache : false`, doing this added a date based timestamp in the URL but still I saw old contents on my dialog. Some SO posts have suggested to destroy the modal but it won't open again I believe. Is there any better approach I can follow to make sure I don't see previous contents in my dialog? I am using chrome as my browser.

Comment: how do you get or retrieve the JSON object `doc_contents`?

Comment: @kolunar  I retrieved it like this `var doc_contents = data_.myContentList;`

Comment: are you sure you have a specific reason using .`.appendTo()` instead of using `.html()` ?

Comment: The answer below worked work me. I was wrong in using `.appendTo()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's not a cached problem, but DOM manipulation problem.
You should replace the content inside `#employee_document_contents` instead of appendTo it.

Try this code inside your callback function:

```
var content = $('<pre />').html(doc_contents[1].text_content);
$('#employee_document_contents').html(content); // Here you replace the content
$('#mydialog').modal("show"); 
$('#mydialog').draggable();
```

Answer (score 0):

From the example provide above, it's hard to understand how the promise object is used. I don't see you using the `data_` object. where is the `doc_contents` variable set? Within a closure or outside of the promising callback?

The fast way to resolve this is to understand your scope and assignments. use *Console.log* / *Network tab in Chrome* / or use *breakpoints*.

or do the following to see all ajax responses

```
$( document ).ajaxSuccess(function( event, xhr, settings ) {
  console.log(xhr.responseText);
});
```

Also you can chain your jQuery calls

```
$('#mydialog').modal("show").draggable();
```